# In Selenium, What is the command to "wait until the page loading stops"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to make the WebDriver wait until the page loading stops completely.

Means, it waits and checks whether entire page has been loaded or not, then only it proceeds with the next line execution.

Answer (score 9):

The biggest problem is that there is no generic, one-size-fits-all solution that will work for even a majority of users. The concept of "when is my page finished loading" is rendered nearly meaningless in today's dynamic, AJAX-heavy, JavaScript-dependent web. One can wait for the browser to determine network traffic is complete, but that doesn't take JavaScript execution into account. One could define "complete" as the page's `onload` event having fired, but that overlooks the possibility of the page using `setTimeout()`. Furthermore, none of these definitions take frames or iframes into account.

When it comes to Selenium, there are a couple of factors to consider. Remember that the Selenium RC API is 10 years old. When it was designed and developed, the architecture of typical web pages made a method like `waitForPageToLoad` practical. The WebDriver API, on the other hand, recognizes the current reality. Individual driver implementations usually will try to wait for a page load during an explicit page navigation (e.g., `driver.get()`), but this wait will be a "best effort", and is *not* a guarantee. Please note that navigation caused by user interaction (e.g., `element.click()`) will be less likely to fully wait, because such interactions are asynchronous, and thus inherently have race conditions.

The correct approach for WebDriver is to wait for the element you want to interact with to appear on the subsequent page. This is best accomplished with a `WebDriverWait` or a similar construct. You might find some of these other constructs in the support library, mainly in those dealing with the Page Object pattern. You could also try setting the implicit wait timeout in your driver instance, but I believe using it obscures intent.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually the default behavior of Selenium - it waits until all requests are complete before going on to the next line of code.

Comment: But it doesn't include javascript & jQuery etc.?

Comment: The answer is a bit simplistic. While mostly correct, it glosses many of the subtleties involved. There are better answers, and I would be very disappointed to see this one become the highest scored answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a design pattern provided through the Selenium support library `SlowLoadableComponent` that would do what you want:  https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/SlowLoadableComponent.html. The gist is that you write your page object to `extend` `SlowLoadableComponent`. You will have to provide implementations for two `abstract` methods in `SlowLoadableComponent`: `load()` and `isLoaded()`

The`isLoaded()` method should check everything you need to consider your page 'loaded'. The `load()` method performs the actions necessary to load your page object. You specify a load timeout for your page object (I do this through the page object's constructor). When you invoke the `get()` method on your page object, which is inherited from `SlowLoadableComponent`, it will call `isLoaded()`. If your page object is not loaded, it will then call `load()` to load your page object. It will continue to do this until your page object is loaded or until your timeout expires.

You will have to define yourself what it means for your page object to be loaded, however. There is no out of the box way for Selenium to determine if your particular page object is loaded or not because these determinations are so context-sensitive. For example, consider a page object representing the login page for a web app. It is 'loaded' if the username and password entry text boxes and the submit login button are visible. This does not apply to a page object representing some other page in a web app. You have to custom tailor the 'is loaded' criteria for any given page object.

Here is a simple example. Basic abstract loadable object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SlowLoadableComponent;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SystemClock;

public abstract class AbstractLoadableComponent<T extends AbstractLoadableComponent<T>> extends SlowLoadableComponent<T> {

    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 30;
    private final WebDriver driver;
    private final int timeoutInSeconds;

    public AbstractLoadableComponent(final WebDriver driver, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
        super(new SystemClock(), timeoutInSeconds);

        this.driver = driver;
        this.timeoutInSeconds = timeoutInSeconds;
        this.load();
    }

    public final WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public final int getTimeoutInSeconds() {
        return timeoutInSeconds;
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), this);
    }
}
```

Basic abstract page object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SlowLoadableComponent;

public abstract class AbstractPage<T extends AbstractPage<T>> extends AbstractLoadableComponent<T> {

    private final String url;

    public AbstractPage(final WebDriver driver) {
        this(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public AbstractPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url) {
        this(driver, url, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public AbstractPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
        super(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
        this.url = url;
    }

    public final String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        super.load();

        if(url != null) {
            getDriver().get(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Basic concrete page object class for a login page:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public final class LoginPage extends AbstractPage<LoginPage>  {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "username")
    private WebElement usernameBox;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password")
    private WebElement passwordBox;

    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "login")
    private WebElement loginButton;

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver) {
        this(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url) {
        this(driver, url, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
        super(driver, url, timeoutInSeconds);
    }

    @Override
    protected final void isLoaded() throws Error {
        try {
            assertTrue(usernameBox.isDisplayed(), "Username text box is not displayed");
            assertTrue(passwordBox.isDisplayed(), "Password text box is not displayed");
            assertTrue(loginButton.isDisplayed(), "Login button is not displayed");
        } catch(NoSuchElementException nsee) {
            throw new Error(nsee);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.manage.implicitlywait(3, TimeUnit.Seconds) will hep.